# PHPMailer Send() function is stopping a script after executing

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send a user the results of a form using the following steps:

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "user@example.com";
    $mail->Password = "passwd";
    $mail->SetFrom("user@example.com");
    $mail->Subject = "Test";
    $mail->Body = mailMaker($data);
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->AddAddress("otheruser@example.com");
    $mail->Send();
```

This is a part of a larger `.php` document which is called by ajax and returns the form data back to the page.

When the `$mail->Send()` function is called the email is sent and everything works fine, but the script ends and I don't get the data back during ajax. I know it is this line because if I comment it out everything works (except the mail isn't sent obviously).

I tried moving the mail methods to another script but I kept getting errors, and was unable to even get a `var_dump()` or anything returned from the ajax. Is there a logical reason `Send()` is stopping the script in this case?

Comment: have you tried put your phpmailer code into a try-catch block? This will help you to get the error...

Comment: I am unfamiliar with try-catch in php. I just ran through the docs and added the block, and called the exception, but i'm not sure where to look to see the message.

Comment: try{ $mail->Send(); }  catch (Exception $e){ echo $e->getMessage(); die(); }  -- And take a look at the message... If you are using ajax, try look at the network tab on firebug or at the chrome console...

Comment: So that's what I tried and I didn't get any message in the Chrome console. I just installed Firebug and I don't think its throwing and error. All I can see is the object that should be returned.

Comment: Wich version of PHPMailer are you using?

Comment: If you want `send()` to throw exceptions, you need to enable them in the constructor: `$mail = new PHPMailer(true);`; otherwise look in the `ErrorInfo` property. You should test this in isolation - you're trying to debug a server-side issue in the client, which isn't going to work well. If there are any errors, expect to find them in your web server's error log. You have debug output enabled - that will likely break anything that's expecting a JSON response.

Comment: You also call `isHTML()` twice.